# REST API with Raspberry Pi and requests

Tags: python-3.x, request, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to capture the response from the following line

`r = requests.get("http://192.168.1.nnn/rest/nodes/24%2076%205C%201/ST", auth=('username', 'passwd'))`

r.status_code looks ok.
I expect the output to look like the following

`<properties>
   <property id="ST" value="0" formatted="Off" uom="%/on/off"/>
</properties>`

How do I get this data?
r.text and r.content do not contain the results.
The above url works in a browser

Answer (score 0):

The response should be in r.text but you need to set the Requests header to match the content-type response. For example if your response content was json, you would set headers like this:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
requests.get("http://192.168.1.nnn/rest/nodes/24%2076%205C%201/ST", auth=('username', 'passwd'), headers=headers)
```

Comment: I actually got it to work without the headers.
URL_results=str(r.content)
However, I am sure the header should be added.